# MySQL Select with alpha wildcards not working

Tags: mysql, select, wildcard

I have a simple table of a single column with rows of `char(12)` like:

```
DRF4482   
DRF4497   
DRF451  
DRF4515  
EHF452  
FJF453  
GKF4573
```

I want to select all of the rows that are between `D` and `F`, and have 4 numbers at the end.  Like `DRF4482`, `DRF4497`, `DRF4515`, etc.  I've tried a number of different wildcard combinations but I get no rows.  I'm using:

```
SELECT * FROM `expired` WHERE id like '%[D-F][A-Z][A-Z]____';
```

I've even tried to broaden it to:

```
SELECT * FROM `expired` WHERE id like '%[D-F]%';
```

and that returns nothing as well.

I've even tried `COLLATE latin1_bin` based on some other posts but that didn't work either.  My table is `utf8`, but I've created a second table as `latin1` and tried a few different collations with the same results - no rows.

Where is my error?

Comment: Pretty sure you want to be using REGEXP  instead of like.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`REGEXP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) instead of `LIKE`. Notice that the syntax is a little different; it doesn't do anything with the SQLish `%` wildcard characters.

So, you want

```
id REGEXP '[D-F][A-Z][A-Z][0-9]{4}'
```

for this app.  Hopefully you don't have multibyte characters in these strings, because MySQL's regexp doesn't work correctly in those circumstances.